# Is there an easy way to scrape a table off a website (after a button press) using python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a table off this [website](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/butleji01/gamelog/2015).  The table of gamelogs is typical formatted html table, but there's a button [image: button to click] that converts the table into a csv array which is more easily parsed.  I was wondering if there was a straightforward way (in python) to download the csv array by simulating a button click.  I've tried selenium, but that seems to open a chrome browser (which I don't want to do).  There has to be an easier way!

Thanks,

Jesse

Answer (score 0):

From @satyaganesh987 blog:

```
import pandas as pd
URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_World_Cup"
tables = pd.read_html(URL,match="Performance details")
print("There are : ",len(tables)," tables")
print("Take look at table 0")
tables[0]
```

For more check the blog: [Scraping Table Data From Websites— using a single line in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/scraping-table-data-from-websites-using-a-single-line-in-python-ba898d54e2bc)

Answer (score 0):

The authors of the website are using Javascript to convert the table to CSV format.
[image: see snapshot]
In cases like this, Selenium is one approach -which you don't like-, or just take the HTML version of the table and write an equivalent function in Python that converts the HTML table to CSV.

They are using [this library](https://d2p3bygnnzw9w3.cloudfront.net/req/202102172/js/bbr/sr-min.js).